# Flutter - adding items to ListView dynamically in Stateless Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm creating a Flutter application, and I have a route to Stateless widget from Stateful widget. Also, I have a ListView with data, and I want to add items dynamically: but I added a ListView to Stateless Widget, because route to Stateful widget doesn't work.

How can fix this?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must show some of your code.

You choose basically convert Stateless Widget to Stateful Widget and define a variable listItem. Then you can call setState after adding some item to your variable.

Otherwise, I recommend using State Management packages, etc. GetX, BLoC, or Provider. You can research them.

Comment: OK. I listen a lot of about State Management Packages. I think, I'll try to use it. Thanks!